# Recording using arecord creates thousands of files

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, audio-recording, alsa

I was trying to use `arecord` to record a wav file, but instead of recording to one file, it created tens of thousands of files (around 60000). This happened after I had installed the alsaequal package. I used to record using the `-f dat` flag with `arecord`, but after I installed alsaequal, this stopped working so I tried to use `-f cd`, which is when this problem occured. I don't know if it is alsaequal that is causing this behavior or the use of the `cd` format. I am using Arch Linux on a Raspberry Pi. The full command that I ran was `arecord -f cd test.wav` and the files it outputted were all named `test-xxxxx.wav` Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this problem?

**Update:** This seems to happen randomly. It will work fine for a bunch of recordings and then I restart or run `arecord` with slightly different arguments, which will cause the problem to occur each time I record (no matter what arguments I use). I haven't been able to find a reproducible pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that when arecord receives a SIGINT it gets upset and
creates thousands of files.  (This will happen if you Ctrl-C whilst it
is recording.)  I'm not sure how to "fix" it (I'd classify it as a
bug, anyway), but I will offer two workarounds:

1. Don't SIGINT, just SIGKILL (`killall -KILL arecord`)
2. To prevent thousands of files being created do the following instead:

   `arecord - > /tmp/sample.wav 2> /dev/null`

   Now, instead of producing sample-1.wav, sample-2.wav, etc, arecord
   sends all it's data to STDOUT, which you redirect to a file of your
   choice.  Messages are printed to STDERR which is redirected to
   /dev/null in this case.  The tradeoff is that instead of thousands
   of files being created, that single file will grow very large -
   which may or may not be considered as an improvement!

As a bonus gift; since the classic "`rm /tmp/sample*.wav`" is likely to
report "too many files"; here is how to clean up the mess (adjust as
appropriate):

```
find /tmp -type f -name sample*.wav -exec rm {} \+
```

Just for the record:

```
$ arecord --version
arecord version 1.0.27 by Jaroslav Kysela <perex@perex.cz>
```

Comment: This seems to have worked, as far as I can tell.